# Problem with STDIN - readinput till no input

Tags: php

I'm writing a PHP CLI script, which when launched will be passed a directive\argument.
so when initially running the script a person would enter say `php test.php -d` (test.php is the script name & `-d` is the argument passed.

after this the script needs to continue reading commands (and perform actions based on those commands) entered till nothing is entered - so the script would then end\quit when nothing entered.

I'm trying to use STDIN (input stream), but at the same time having a while loop on a readline -till nothing entered would be feasible - using STDIN seemed better, but ive never used it before.

current attempt with code:

```
    <?php
    
    if (sizeof($argv) <= 1)
      echo "missing argument";
      //needs to allow a person to then enter an argument.
    else {
      if (argv[2] == "-d"
      //do something
      $f = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
      while ($line = fgets($f)) {
         if (empty($line)) {
            fclose($f);
            exit;
         }
       dosomething(); //do something relative to argument entered
       echo $line;  //just display what was entered
       }
}
    ?>
```

so in the end, the console would be something kinda like:

```
php test.php -d  
d was entered (response the user sees)
-t something  
t something was entered (response the user sees)

(program quits due to return\empty line)
```

Comment: And what's the actual problem you're asking about?

Comment: Do u think $line will be empty (before you type anything) and so it quits immediately?

Comment: [fgets](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php): Reading ends when length - 1 bytes have been read, or a newline (**which is included in the return value**)

Comment: You are missing ) in the 2nd if statement

Comment: `$argv` doesn't include the `php` command itself. So `-d` is in `$argv[1]`, not `$argv[2]`.